# Attaching params to form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, a micropost is simply called an "item". On each user's "show" page, there should be a form for making a new "item" that belongs to that user.

I am getting stuck making such a form.

When the form is submitted, the controller action below fires:

```
@user = User.find_by(name: params[:name])
@user.items.create(item_params)
redirect_to 'root'
```

By the way, the 'item_params' method is

`params.require(:item).permit(:title, :content, :user_id)`

I am getting an error about the second line. The error is

`undefined method 'items' for nil:NilClass`

I checked in the rails console whether I could make a new item by first selecting a user by name

`@user = User.find_by(name: "tester1")`

then create an item for it with the below statement:

`@user.items.create(title: "new_item_title", content: "new_item_content")`

and the new item was created as expected. I cannot explain the browser error, though.

---

**EDIT**

The form in question is on a "show_user". Here is the log for the HTTP request for that page:

```
Started GET "/center/show_user?utf8=%E2%9C%93&name=tester&commit=Search" for 12
.0.0.1 at 2014-03-19 11:46:51 -0700
Processing by CenterController#show_user as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "name"=>"tester", "commit"=>"Search"}
  ←[1m←[35mUser Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."
ame" = 'tester' LIMIT 1
  Rendered center/show_user.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 18.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

The form is hosted on this page. Here is the request that is sent with submission of the form:

```
Started POST "/center/show_user" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-19 11:47:14 -0700
Processing by CenterController#create_item_owned as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"P6mb63rhTHx6Q17zhfu4WXErG5Pb0
8t0d/L1RppKAl0=", "item"=>{"title"=>"uno", "content"=>"uno1"}, "commit"=>"Save I
tem"}
  ←[1m←[36mUser Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users
"."name" IS NULL LIMIT 1←[0m
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `items' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/center_controller.rb:18:in `create_item_owned'
```

So no information about the user is being passed along with the parameters when the form is submitted. How how I fix this?

Here are my relevant routes:

```
get "center/show_user/" => 'center#show_user'

post "center/show_user" => 'center#create_item_owned'
```

The "create_item_owned" action is the one described at the beginning of this question. 
The "show_user" action is

`@user = User.find_by(name: params[:name])
 @new_item = Item.new`

How should I forward along those parameters in such a way that the new object created by the form is automatically associated with the specific user in the database (along with automatic creation of foreign keys)?

---

My form is

```
<%= form_for :item do |x| %>
    Title:  <%= x.text_field :title  %> <br>    
    Content:    <%= x.text_field :content %> <br>   
    <%= x.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: so does `params[:name]` match the name for a valid user?

Comment: Can u paste your form? is params[:name] passing name?

Comment: @sevenseacat updated question in response to your comments

Comment: @AnkitG updated question in response to your comments

Comment: so `params[:name]` is actually nil, so no user is getting found.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might still have to find by id rather than by name. The name might not be passed in the params. You should check your logs to see what params are being sent.

Comment: There is no param being sent that relates to the user who the show page belongs to. How do I forward a parameter in this way? I have updated my question to show the log including the param info.